# EF Get the values of a .include

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have the following on my DAL layer:

```
    public List<customer> SelectAll()
    {
        using (ubmmsEntities db = new ubmmsEntities())
        {
            var result = db.customers
                         .Include(p => p.project_codes)
                         .OrderBy(c=>c.customer_name)
                         .ToList();
            return result;

        }
    }
```

Basically this returns to me a List of Customers and their respective project codes. With the returned List I fill in a drop down list on my View:

```
        dropdown.DisplayMember = "customer_name";
        dropdown.ValueMember = "id";
        dropdown.DataSource = list;
```

This part works fine. But I have a second drop down which is meant to display the project codes based on the selected "customer_name" from the customer dropdown

The below piece of code filter the results I need for the second drop down:

```
var projects = list.Where(x => x.id.Equals(ddlCustomer.SelectedValue)).ToList();
```

So, the `projects` return me an object with count=1. In execution if I mouse over I get `[0] {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies....}`
drilling down over that I get a list of the project codes (the count). And if I drill down again I will get the actual list, with the information from the `include` as planned. So far so good.

The problem is that I do now know how to access them in order to have the project codes added to my project drop down.

I tried to set `dropproject.DisplayMember = "project_name"` (which is what I am trying to get to), but all I was able to get is the object type `{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies....}` and not the value of its actual members.

Now, I know I could just create a method on my DAL to access my project codes based on the selected customer text from the dropdown and sort this out fast, but since I know that I have an object which already contains my customers, their ids and the project codes, I would like to learn a way to get my project_names stored on my project_codes table.

It might be a solution for future problems... or maybe learn why I shouldn't do it (I can think of some scenarios where it would cause performance problems)

Let me know if the question and information suffices, any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to the following:

```
var projectCodes = list.Where(x => x.id.Equals(ddlCustomer.SelectedValue))
                       .Select(x => x.project_codes)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will give you the product codes of the customer selected. With that list you can query the projects:

```
var projects = db.projects.Where(p => projectCodes.Contains(p.code)).ToList();
```

(I assumed some names, but this should get you there)

Comment: Actually, I just needed the first part of your solution. Setting the DisplayMember and the ValuesMembers and the DataSource to projectCodes are providing me with the project codes names on my drop down.

Answer (score 2):

Since you load customers including projects, you don't need to use a query to get projects of a customer. It's enough to use `Projects` property of your customer (or what ever complex property it is, like project_codes):

```
var customer = (Customer)(customerComboBox.SelectetItem);
if(customer!=null)
{
    var projects = customer.Projects.ToList();
    //. . . 
}
```

Comment: I missed clarifying the information. The method to access the database is in a DAL layer and returns a List. The dropdowns are on the View and this I cannot access the properties, that is why I am trying to work with the list.

Comment: What's the problem of useing `Projects` property of a `Customer`? You have a `Customer` object that has a `Projects` property which contains list of projects of the customer. Can you describe how it may break the rules? Or how can it be relevant to the DAL? I just get the customer from the combo box and I know it contains also projects and used them. The code is just related to UI layer.

Comment: It's strange why you want to use a linq query while projects are present in the selected customer object! The first part of the other answer is just a bad way of getting what I described!

Comment: It could be me, but I don't get to the first part of your solution work whatsoever on the view. It states that it is not possible to convert combobox to customer and other different errors based on different attempts I do to adapt your code to what I am looking for. I did manage to adapt your code to my needs on my DAL, but I fail to do the same when moving it to View. Sorry for "newbiness/dumbness" but you might want to clarify?

Comment: It's because of your mistake. Pay attention, I converted `SelectedItem` of `customerComboBox` to `Customer` this way: `(Customer)(customerComboBox.SelectetItem);`. It doesn't have anything to do with converting a combo box to customer. Forget about `DAL`, your question is all about UI after getting a `List<Customer>` while a `Customer` includes all its `Project` objects. Since you set `List<Customer>` as `DataSource` of `ComboBox` then items of `ComboBox` are `Customer`.

Comment: You don't need to be sorry, but you need to ask about an answer when you have problem applying the solution, that's why I say *Let me know if you have any question about the answer or any problem applying the solution.* :)